# Loop through mysqli query from two tables to print itemeized receipts for each customer

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables created for and online ordering system that look as such:
  Table 1 (orders)

### orderid |  customername  | email

15     |   joe          | joe@s.com
 16     |   ron          | ron@this.com
 17     |   tim          | tim@nice.com
 18     |   sue          | sue@rad.com

and: Table 2 (orderitems)

### id  |  orderid | orderitems

1   |  15      | sourdough
2   |  15      | four grain
3   |  16      | original fruit
4   |  16      | finnish rye
5   |  16      | sourdough
6   |  17      | sourdough
7   |  18      | original fruit

The orderid's are the same on both tables and I am trying to figure out how I can loop through all orderid's on the orderitems table to to print receipts for each customer.

so far i have a the mysqli statement:

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.orderid, a.customername, a.email, b.orderid, b.menuitem FROM orders a, orderitems b WHERE a.orderid = b.orderid';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<td>" . $row['customername'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['menuitem'] . "</td>";
}
```

this gets everything thing I need except I would like to separate each order individually so I can send each customer a receipt.  I am not sure how to achieve this and I have exhausted all search terms here to try to find what I am looking for.  
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an explicit [`join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) with an `on` (or `using` in this case where the two columns are exact match) clause. You then can [`group by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) the `order`s by their id and concatenate the items of the order with [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
select o.customername as name, o.email as email, group_concat(oi.orderitems) as items
from orders as o
join orderitems as oi using (orderid)
group by orderid
```

the `on` syntax would be:

```
select o.customername as name, o.email as email, group_concat(oi.orderitems) as items
from orders as o
join orderitems as oi 
on o.orderid = oi.orderid
group by orderid
```

You were using a loose `join` but the explicit is cleaner and more accurate.

> The conditional_expr used with ON is any conditional expression of the form that can be used in a WHERE clause. Generally, the ON clause serves for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the WHERE clause restricts which rows to include in the result set

Comment: Chris this is such a helpful answer. Hope you get credit for it. I learned something from it so thanks. Say, why did you choose `join` rather than `left join`?

Comment: If the order doesn't have any items I assume the OP doesn't care about it.